# Listeners used in child Xml are not called when I execute TestNg Scripts using parent Xml

Tags: testng

Listeners used in child Xml are not called when I execute TestNg Scripts using parent Xml. But, if I execute child xml directly without parent xml , listeners are working fine. Please help me out.

**Parent Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parent Suite">
 <suite-files>
  <suite-file path="mdTests.xml"></suite-file>
  <suite-file path="csTests.xml"></suite-file>
  <suite-file path="cvTests.xml"></suite-file> 
  <suite-file path="cdIETests.xml"></suite-file>
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**mdTests.xml (child xml all are almost similar).**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MD Suite" verbose="2">
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="BaseSetUp.ScreenShotListeners"/> 
  <listener class-name="BaseSetUp.TestNGCustomReportListener"/>
</listeners> 
<test name="Test with Internet Expplorer Browser">
 <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/> 
 <classes>     
  <class name="com.Tests.CV.Testing">
   <methods>
    <include name="tc_001"/>
    <include name="tc_002"/>
   </methods>
   </class>   
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue related to this ( See [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1284) ) which was fixed in TestNG 6.11 (See [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L59) ). So please try running this using TestNG v6.11 or higher.

Comment: Thank you  it's working. But, again they are  showing some warnings on which TestNg guys are working .

Comment: @DeepakS - What sort of warnings are you talking about ? Can you please let me know ? Because I am also part of the core TestNG group. So it would help if you can please add specifics. On a side note, please accept my answer if it answered your question.